# Installing wifi driver error 127

Tags: makefile, compat-wireless

I've got problem with installation wifi driver, terminal says error 127.

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-32-generic'
root@jakub-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/jakub/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc# make install
make: execvp: ./scripts/update-initramfs: Permission denied
make: *** [uninstall] Error 127
```

any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To install software you need root privileges. So the correct command is `sudo make install`.

You are asked for your **own** password.